# match regex only in groups between dash

Tags: regex, nginx

i want to match the following format:

matchnumbersandcharacter-matchanynumbers

example:

```
mxlgl8ldlsl2-282
1h2hsh5hshk5-31293
9g96mdh46dhd-3129652524
```

group 1 is matchanynumbersandcharacter and group 2 matchanynumbers

i cant get it to work to match only group 1 and 2 separate it always include the dash or the whole match.

Comment: More simple is `(\w+)-(\d+)` (`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
^([^\W_]+)[-–](\d+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
>
> **`([^\W_]+)`** - Represents first capturing group matching only from `[0-9A-Za-z]` 1 or more time.
>
> **`[-–]`** - Matches either from `-` and `–`([**Em-dash**](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphens-and-dashes/#:%7E:text=When%20to%20Use%20Em%20Dashes,than%20a%20period%20or%20semicolon.)).
>
> **`(\d+)`** - Matches digits `[0-9]` one or more times.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/KLqjJc/5/)

Comment: that was it, i wasnt paying attention to the Em-dash.

Comment: A big thanks to @JvdV for helping me always in continuous improvements of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure
`([a-zA-Z0-9]*)-(\d*)`
would work. I tested it in a regex tester and it works for your criteria. But do you want to capture the dash too? Then use `((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)-(?:\d*))` (I didn't try to compact that). BTW, I can't comment (this should be a comment) so I'm answering.

Comment: I edited it. Now, only letters of the english alphabet (uppercase or lowercase) and numbers will be detected

Comment: Your tries are also worth it. Just correct your little flaws and your answer will be fine. +1 for your efforts